# How to use firefox ui in vagrant box

Tags: firefox, jenkins, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm new to **Vagrant**

I've installed **vagrant** and vagrant box for **ubuntu/xenial64** on my ubuntu machine. (Ubuntu box on Ubuntu host OS)

Inside the vagrant box, I installed openjdk-8, firefox, jenkins.

How do I access the firefox browser UI which is installed in the Vagrant box so that I can have access jenkins server.

After entering into box using **vagrant ssh**, When I type **firefox** in vagrant box, it is saying

**Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays**

Same thing's happening when I try **sudo firefox**

Here is my vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.68.8"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant starts VMs in headless mode per default. You can configure it to start with a display by adding this to your `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end
```

Then restart the VM.

```
vagrant reload
```